# NoData values change after saving in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst

I'm using ArcGIS Pro 3.0 to process a series of .tif files. I'm going to process these images in a program that requires NoData and nan values to be set to a numerical value, like -3. I have code to set these null values to -3, and it works when the output is a geodatabase object, but not when I save it. When I save it to a file folder, it does not change the NoData values at all. Why does this happen, and how can I get my saved outputs to have changed NoData values?
Here is my code:

```
from arcpy.sa import *
inras = r"G:\My Drive\work\Northern Animal Ecology Lab\sentinelrst\rst2019\bl\20190129.tif"
outCon = Con(IsNull(inras), -3, inras)
outCon.save(r"G:\My Drive\work\Northern Animal Ecology Lab\sentinelrst\rst2019\20190129null.tif")
```

Comment: I'd add line inras = Raster(inras)

Answer (score 0):

Its because your chosen output file format is TIF. ESRI tools don't honour compression and may be other settings. In your sample code you are using the IsNull() and Con() tools. I typically rectify this by running the file through through the Copy Raster tool to set bit depth, nodata and compression.